# UILabel Won't Pin To Bottom of NavBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

Is there a way to get the label to pin to the bottom instead of the top?

```
    var timeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.textColor = .gray
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    func setTitle(subtitle:UILabel) -> UIView {
        
        let navigationBarHeight = Int(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)
        let navigationBarWidth = Int(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.width)

        let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navigationBarWidth, height: navigationBarHeight))
        titleView.addSubview(subtitle)

        return titleView

    }
```

then in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = setTitle(subtitle: timeLabel)
```

[image]

UPDATE

[image: Image3]

Comment: You can calculate the navigationBar height and set-top as earlier but with this height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your label with text alignment to right:

```
var timeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

now in viewDidLoad add the label to nav bar and set constraints:

```
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
   timeLabel.text = "FRIDAY, SEPTEMBER 18" // set here your string date
   navigationBar.addSubview(timeLabel)
   timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true // set the constant how do you prefer
   timeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
   timeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
   timeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
 }
```

**UPDATE FOR TABLE VIEW SCROLLING**

Add UIScrollViewDelegate to your controller, after that implement scrollViewWillBeginDragging and tableView willDisplay method like this:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentSize.height > 0 && ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.safeAreaInsets.top) == 0) {
        timeLabel.alpha = 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        timeLabel.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

**BONUS**

for a cool effect when the timeLabel show again add animation in tableView willDisplay like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.timeLabel.alpha = 1
        } completion: { (_) in
            print("visible TimeLabel")
        }
    }
}
```

this is the result

[image]

**UPDATE FOR GILL**

This explained above is not the rule but just a trick, I advise you to consider putting the date in the header so you would no longer have problems with the title: delete scrollViewWillBeginDragging and tableView willDisplay function and add viewForHeaderInSection, to do this delete existent timeLabel constraints and declare viewForHeaderInSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9018846154, green: 0.9020112157, blue: 0.9018446803, alpha: 1)
    v.addSubview(timeLabel)
    // declare here your timeLabel constraints
    timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor).isActive = true
    timeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    timeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    return v
}
```

now set the hight of your header:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: but when you scroll it also goes into the normal size nav bar, is there a way to remove it when scrolling up and it retracts to normal nav bar @Fabio

Comment: @GILL I update my answer, if satisfy your question check it is the right answer and upvote :)

Comment: check my update, is there a way to not show the word "monitor" in small nav bar? @Fabio

Comment: @GILL I don’t try This solution because my mac is at home, but you can try to put in scrollViewWillBeginDragging this line: navigationItem.title = “” and in tableView willDisplay navigationItem.title = “Monitor” ... let me know if it works

Comment: weird its not working correctly for me, not sure why

Comment: i got it to work, but for some reason it the alpha only goes back to 1 when i scroll all the way up a second time(like how you would to refresh tableview) @Fabio

Comment: @GILL This is just a trick, it isn't the rule...in alternative consider my new answer update...